# Android SDK sample app question:

Tags: android, api, title

If you go into the standard Note pad accessory application, the first available note menu entry is going to be...

```
<untitled>
```

My question is this:  Where is "`<untitled>`" coming from in the code?  The code is in the NotePad sample in the SDK if you want to built a project from existing source real fast.  I just can't find where "`<untitled>`" is spelled out anywhere in the source or resources.

(Else, is this instead some kind of ultra low level string that Android's API hands to the GUI if there's nothing specified for a title?  Which can't be changed?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the NotePadProvider.java appears that this string cames from android.R.string. To find that file you need to go here: SDKpath/platforms/version_you_are_programming/data/res/values. There is the string.xml file and that file is internal to the OS, I doubt you can change it.

Comment: Thank's Adrian.  I'll take a look at that.